# Optional url parameter in django 2.2

Tags: python, django, regex, url

I am working on a solution where in the application I would like to have an url with an optional parameter, if it is not there, the location is for Germany. Below is my code with urls for django 2.2 and view.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<country>', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'data/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset = DataSet.objects.filter(location=self.request.GET.get('country', 'Germany'))
    return context
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two `url`s here, one with a `country` parameter, and another one without:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), kwargs={'country': 'Germany'}),
    path('<country>', HomeView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

or you can let the Django view itself inject `'Germany'` in case of default:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view()),
    path('<country>', HomeView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

Note that the URL parameters are stored in the `self.kwargs`, not in `self.request.GET`:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = 'data/index.html'
    model = DataSet

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            location=self.kwargs.get('country', 'Germany')
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and solution. Please tell me, this is solution coresponding with documentation, or kind of hack?